# send System.out.println to a file

Tags: java

In my company in our project we have lot of system.out.prinltn and we are finding very difficult to see all logs on console. is it possible to capture the system.out.println to a file? Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything???

Comment: The easiest way is on OS level, just redirect stdout to a file when you start the process.

Comment: *"In my company in our project we have lot of system.out.prinltn ..."*  - Then you have a serious problem with Code Quality in your company.    It is likely to burn you ... or your clients / customers ... in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to redirect stdout on DOS or any *nix type Operating System.

```
java -jar somefile.jar > my_file.txt
```

If you're using a *nix system you can also use the `tee` command (which will output to the stdout **and** to a file) like

```
java -jar somefile.jar | tee my_file.txt
```

Both also support appending to the file

```
java -jar somefile.jar >> my_file.txt
```

or

```
java -jar somefile.jar | tee -a my_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to achieve this, the easiest one is while running through command prompt

```
java class_name >file_name.txt
```

It would be great if you can provide more details on this.